# JQuery changing HTML but not updating screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

[SOLVED]: I fixed it by putting the `div` where the text must be changed in a separate file (along with the javascript for doing so), then linking it in using an `iframe`.

I'm working on a project and I used a template from FreeFrontEnd (it was a nice carousel template). I want to change some text through JQuery. It seems like the page is being blocked from updating - when I query the HTML that was changed, it returns the changed value, despite it not updating the actual HTML on the screen or in inspect element.

I've tried with plain JavaScript which didn't work either. To test, I tried multiple browsers and none worked.

This code is for changing the HTML (it's called from a button press):

```
function changeShowcase(inc=1) {
  showcased = showcased + inc;
  if (showcased == projectNames.length) {
    showcased = 0;
  } else if (showcased < 0) {
    showcased = projectNames.length - 1;
  }
  $("#projectName").html(projectNames[showcased]);
  $("#projectDesc").html(projectDescs[showcased]);
  $("#showcase source").attr("src",projectVideos[showcased]);
  $("#showcase")[0].load();
}
```

I believe the problem may lie in the template I'm using (which I don't fully understand because I don't use JQuery that much).

My question is, in a nutshell, does any of this code which I don't understand cache the HTML somehow so it won't update?

```
const appendControls = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    $('.carousel__control').append(`<a href="#" data-index="${i}"></a>`);
  }
  let height = $('.carousel__control').children().last().outerHeight();

  $('.carousel__control').css('height', 30 + limit * height);
  $controls = $('.carousel__control').children();
  $controls.eq(activeIndex).addClass('active');
};

const setIndexes = () => {
  $('.spinner').children().each((i, el) => {
    $(el).attr('data-index', i);
    limit++;
  });
};

const duplicateSpinner = () => {
  const $el = $('.spinner').parent();
  const html = $('.spinner').parent().html();
  $el.append(html);
  $('.spinner').last().addClass('spinner--right');
  $('.spinner--right').removeClass('spinner--left');
};

const paintFaces = () => {
  $('.spinner__face').each((i, el) => {
    const $el = $(el);
    let color = $(el).attr('data-bg');
    $el.children().css('backgroundImage', `url(${getBase64PixelByColor(color)})`);
  });
};

const getBase64PixelByColor = hex => {
  if (!canvas) {
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = 1;
    canvas.width = 1;
  }
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = hex;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1, 1);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
  }
  return false;
};

const prepareDom = () => {
  setIndexes();
  paintFaces();
  duplicateSpinner();
  appendControls();
};

const spin = (inc = 1) => {
  if (disabled) return;
  if (!inc) return;
  activeIndex += inc;
  disabled = true;

  if (activeIndex >= limit) {
    activeIndex = 0;
  }

  if (activeIndex < 0) {
    activeIndex = limit - 1;
  }

  const $activeEls = $('.spinner__face.js-active');
  const $nextEls = $(`.spinner__face[data-index=${activeIndex}]`);
  $nextEls.addClass('js-next');

  if (inc > 0) {
    $stage.addClass(SPIN_FORWARD_CLASS);
  } else {
    $stage.addClass(SPIN_BACKWARD_CLASS);
  }

  $controls.removeClass('active');
  $controls.eq(activeIndex).addClass('active');

  setTimeout(() => {
    spinCallback(inc);
  }, SPIN_DUR, inc);
};

const spinCallback = inc => {

  $('.js-active').removeClass('js-active');
  $('.js-next').removeClass('js-next').addClass('js-active');
  $stage.
  addClass(DISABLE_TRANSITIONS_CLASS).
  removeClass(SPIN_FORWARD_CLASS).
  removeClass(SPIN_BACKWARD_CLASS);

  $('.js-active').each((i, el) => {
    const $el = $(el);
    $el.prependTo($el.parent());
  });
  setTimeout(() => {
    $stage.removeClass(DISABLE_TRANSITIONS_CLASS);
    disabled = false;
  }, 100);

};

const attachListeners = () => {

  document.onwheel = e => {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      spin(1);
    } else {
      spin(-1);
    }

  };

  $controls.on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (disabled) return;
    const $el = $(e.target);
    const toIndex = parseInt($el.attr('data-index'), 10);
    spin(toIndex - activeIndex);

  });
};

const assignEls = () => {
  $stage = $('.carousel__stage');
};

const init = () => {
  assignEls();
  prepareDom();
  attachListeners();
};
```

I expect it to change the HTML on the screen, but I think the above code may stop this for some reason.

Comment: Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: where do you call init()?

Comment: @ChrisG I don't know what the code does so I don't know what's relevant sorry

Comment: @djolf page load I think

Comment: i think.load() refreshes your page, and therefore init() is called again, so your html is lost. I don't think you should be using .load(), but I don't know what your html looks like, so I can't tell you what you should be using.